Redshift admin cannot see svl_user_info table
Even when I connect as the admin superuser, Redshift will not let me access the table:
svl_user_info
so queries like
select * from svl_user_info
do not work. The error message is:
ERROR: permission denied for relation svl_user_info

This does not work because the table exists only for provisioned Redshift clusters. If you are using the a Serverless Redshift cluster, the table has a different name, which is:
SVV_USER_INFO
try this (on Serverless clusters)
select * from svv_user_info;
To see your user info.
